# Moving array results from one json object to another

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a new created json data model in _initializeData. The  aim is when the user tries to remove the item in the cart I want to store that item in this new data model. So on click of remove button, I am reading the json data model which has all the items in the cart and then using the index of the removed element copying that result into the new model. It works fine if I remove only one item. But if I press remove on another item, the previous entry from the new model is over-written by the new entry. It does not hold all the entries like an array.

```
_initializeData: function () {
        var removedData = {};  // new model for removed parts
        removedData.removedParts = [];
        this.removedItems = new JSONModel(removedData);
        this.getView().setModel(this.removedItems, "removedItems");
 }

// button click
onRemovePart: function (oEvent) {  
        var idx = this.getView().byId("table").getSelectedIndex();

        // retrieveing the model which has all the parts from the table 
        var data = this.getView().getModel("materialData").getProperty("/partsData");

        // reading the removed item data 
        var removedPart = data[idx];

        // assigning it to the new model. But it does not hold multiple 
        entries rather over-writes the previous one
        this.getView().getModel("removedItems").setProperty("/removedParts", removedPart);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are overwritting the complete object on the model: removedItems.

Since, you overwrite it, old data is lost. So, all you need to do is fetch the old removed item array, push an element into it, and then set it to model.

```
   _initializeData: function () {
        var removedData = {};  // new model for removed parts
        removedData.removedParts = [];
        this.removedItems = new JSONModel(removedData);
        this.getView().setModel(this.removedItems, "removedItems");
 }

// button click
onRemovePart: function (oEvent) {  
        var idx = this.getView().byId("table").getSelectedIndex();

        // retrieveing the model which has all the parts from the table 
        var data = this.getView().getModel("materialData").getProperty("/partsData");

        // reading the removed item data 
        var removedPart = data[idx];

        // assigning it to the new model. But it does not hold multiple 
        entries rather over-writes the previous one
        // Get the old deleted items first :
        var oDeletedItems = this.getView().getModel("removedItems").getProperty("/removedParts");
        oDeletedItems.removedParts.push(removedPart); // the array is removedParts and oDeletedItems is the obejct which stores the array as per _initlaise method
        this.getView().getModel("removedItems").setProperty("/removedParts", oDeletedItems);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you please help me with this issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55841138/sap-ui5-tables-column-sorting-is-lost-after-table-model-is-refreshed

Answer (score 2):

Use `Array.slice()` to avoid references. Here, the reference is causing overriding behaviour

Comment: I did the following but still it over write and only one entry is present                                     
           var idx = this.getView().byId("table").getSelectedIndex();
                                                                                                                  
           var data = this.getView().getModel("orderParts").getProperty("/orderPartsData");
    var removed = data.splice(idx, 1);  
                                                this.removedItems.setProperty("/removedParts", removed);